# Using compute() to convert images in different thread kills isolate

Tags: multithreading, loops, flutter, dart, dart-isolates

Basically I used an isolate to convert a changeable number of image files from a system directory using the Image package and the Foundation Isolate.

```
await compute(xyzFunc, abcArg);
```

The function which does the things will take the list of image paths in the arguments

```
xyzFunc(abcArg) {
    for(String path in abcArg) {
        resize(path);
```

This will go until some point and throws an error of main() spawn exited with some error. The isolate was killed. There's no indication of any message anywhere. Need help in this.`enter code here`

Comment: How many images do you convert?
Have you tried to wrap `resize` in `try`/`catch` and print the error? Have you tried setting a breakpoint? Perhaps you are just not awaiting async execution and the code completed correctly, but just the result is not available?

Comment: Yes resize is within try-catch, and I am gracefully handling error there. The issue is with isolate. I am not enclosing that within try-catch as it sounded odd, and no the log I created doesn't give success message on completion which happens without isolate (but with jank and stutter).